# Binding NSArray between MonoTouch and Objective C

Tags: xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I have created a static library and trying to bind it to Monotouch using [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough#3.1.1.creating-a-fat-binary)

In the binding i want to pass NSArray from MonoTouch to Objective C. I have it defined in ApiDefinition.cs like
NSObject [] DataArray { get; set; }

- When i try to pass string array from MonoTouch

var b = new[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };

get following error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject[]

- When i try to pass NSArray from MonoTouch

NSArray array1 = NSArray.FromObjects ("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3");

get following error

Cannot implicitly convert type MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray to MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject[]

How do i pass an Array from MonotOuch to Objective C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple choices when binding an objective-c array, e.g. you could have used `NSArray` over `NSObject[]`. I prefer the later but both are valid options.

```
NSArray array1 = NSArray.FromObjects ("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3");
```

Using an `NSArray` would make the above code work since it returns an `NSArray`.

OTOH you have chosen `NSObject[]` so you must follow your decision, i.e. use an array of `NSObject`

```
var b = new[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
```

The above would use an array of `System.String`. There's no direct conversion between `string` and `NSObject`. You can re-write this as:

```
var b = new NSObject [] { new NSString ("Item 1"), new NSString ("Item 2"), new NSString ("Item 3") };
```

which should satisfy the compiler and *likely*, can't be sure without seeing it, is what your native API wants.

Note: if the **native** API accept an array of `NSString` then you can bind it at as `NSString[]`.